# javascript function with in function in variable

Tags: javascript

I have a doubt

**My Code :-**

```
function f() { 
    var g = function() 
    { 
    return 1;
    } 
    return g; 
  };
```

How do I can call g? I want to return 1 once and again I want to return g.

I did a Research I found a solution

How we can call g is:-

```
f()();
```

Why this is ?? What is `f()();` in JavaScript. why not we can achieve this using `f.g` or something.

How can I return g from the function f ??

Please clarify my doubts ?

Comment: please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How can I return g from that function?

You *are* returning `g` from "that function", assuming "that function" is `f`. Since `f` returns a function you are able to invoke the return value with `f()()`. It's pretty much the same as this:

```
var returnedFunction = f();
returnedFunction();
```

> why not we can achieve this using `f.g` or something?

Because `g` is not a property of `f`. I'm not entirely sure what you're aiming for, but perhaps you wanted `f` to be a constructor, and instances of it to have a method `g`?

```
function f() {
    // Constructor function
}
f.prototype.g = function () {
    // Method
};
var myF = new f();
myF.g(); // Now `g` is accessible as a property of the instance
```

You could alternatively have intended `g` to be a static property of `f`:

```
function f() {
    // JS has first-class functions so you can set properties on them
}
f.g = function () {
    // Static method of `f`
};
f.g();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `f()` is returning a function and the second `()` means you are calling that function.

Think of it like this

```
var g = f();
g();
```

Except when you do `f()()` you are basically inlining the variable.

If you wanted to call it using `f.g()` you would need to declare `f` as an object or add `g` as a property.

```
function f() {
  this.g = function() {
    return 1;
  };
}
new f().g();

or

var f = {
  g: function() {
    return 1;
  }
}
f.g();
```

But I am not 100% what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Because you `return g` which is a function. This function returned can be called again.

You `call f()` which returns a function which can be called again `f()()` (second parenthesis).
In two parts:

```
1. var returnValue = f(); // returnValue = function g() { return 1;}
2. returnValue(); // execute function
```

Answer (score 0):

`f()();` can be roughly translated to:

```
var g=f();//return g
g();//invocation of g
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
 var f = function(){};
 f.prototype={
        g : function() 
     { 
        return 1;
     } 
};
```

now you can use it as

```
    var v = new f();
    alert(v.g()); // --> 1
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`. I have no idea what you're trying to do with that...

Comment: Yes that was mistake, See the edits. 
I was not aware you posted the same, I was writing this while you had not posted the answer.